# How to build and deploy an app to Firebase using Nx and NextJs

Tags: firebase, next.js, nx-monorepo, nx.dev

I create an app using [@nx/next](https://nx.dev/nx-api/next). So basically a `nextJs 13` app using `app routing` using `nx`.

Now, I created my project, worked inside my `apps/projectName/app` folder, and create a few `libs/libName/lib` etc... like a normal Nx repository.

I now arrived at a step where I would like to build and deploy a first draft of my work. I setup firebase

```
firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
firebase init hosting
```

And followed the step adding `hosting` and `firestore` (since I also use firestore) and accepting the default config once it detected my `nextJs` project.

I ended up with

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "asia-east1"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, as the route of my built project is `dist/apps/projectName` I changed to

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": "dist/apps/projectName",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "asia-east1"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, running deploy channel now trigger the following:

`firebase hosting:channel:deploy --project projectName testChannel`

> Error: Could not find the next executable.

When I create a new clean project without Nx, it s pretty straightforward but with Nx, I am not sure what I am supposed to deploy even tho it looks similar structure as my build folder. I am unsure what is the correct configuration to allow deployment of a NextJs app inside a NX repository using firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like to this day monorepo are not supported.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6049

I will try to play with the config manually a bit and edit if I find a solution.